# @ArquillianResource returns null URL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, testng, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test a very simple REST web service:

- a `jboss-web.xml` file
- an `Application` class:

  ```
  @ApplicationPath("/")
  public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {}
  ```
- a `Resource` class:

  ```
  @Path("/")
  public class Resource {
    @GET String get() { return "OK"; }
  }
  ```

---

My test class uses the `@ArquillianResource` annotation:

```
public class ResourceTest extends Arquillian {

  @ArquillianResource URL baseURL;

  @Deployment
  public static WebArchive create() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                     .addClasses(Resource.class, Application.class);
  }

  @Test public void get() { /* test Resource here */ }
}
```

I have tried with `@Deployment(testable = false)`, `@Deployment(Testable = true)`, I have also tried to add `@RunAsClient` annotation to the test method.

But I always get the same exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field java.net.URL com.assylias.test.arquillian.ResourceTest.baseURL

at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:71)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)

[...]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value: org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.enricher.resource.URLResourceProvider@babafc2
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.lookup(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:133)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:67)
```

---

For reference, pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could it be that I'm using an embedded container as opposed to a remote container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing works with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it seems that the issue is that the embedded profile doesn't support that feature.